# How to loading XML files from a file

Tags: xml, linq, linq-to-xml, asp.net-3.5

**my xml is below:**

```
<Demo>
    <ClientCompanyId CompanyId="1">
        <MyMenu>
            <module MenuType="0" ModID="Mod1" ModuleID="1" Perm="False" Text="Basic Settings">
                <menu MID="1-1" MenuDescription="Mod" MenuType="0" ModuleID="1" ParentID="Mod1" Perm="False" Text="Forms">
                    <Leaf LeafNode="true" MID="1-3" MenuDescription="" MenuType="0" ModuleID="1" ModuleMenuID="1-3" ParentID="1" Perm="False" TargetUrl="" Text="LookUp"/>
                    <submenu MID="1-4" MenuDescription="" MenuType="0" ModuleID="1" ParentID="1" Perm="False" Text="Bank Branch">
                        <Leaf LeafNode="true" MID="1-5" MenuDescription="" MenuType="0" ModuleID="1" ModuleMenuID="1-5" ParentID="4" Perm="False" TargetUrl="" Text="BO Category"/>
                    </submenu>
                </menu>
                <menu MID="1-2" MenuDescription="Mod" MenuType="0" ModuleID="1" ParentID="Mod1" Perm="False" Text="Reports">
                    <Leaf LeafNode="true" MID="1-6" MenuDescription="" MenuType="0" ModuleID="1" ModuleMenuID="1-6" ParentID="2" Perm="False" TargetUrl="" Text="Cheque Type"/>
                    <Leaf LeafNode="true" MID="1-7" MenuDescription="" MenuType="0" ModuleID="1" ModuleMenuID="1-7" ParentID="2" Perm="False" TargetUrl="" Text="Stock Exchange"/>
                </menu>
            </module>
        </MyMenu>
    </ClientCompanyId>
</Demo>
```

**my linq syntax is below:**

```
 XDocument loaded = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Menu_Settings.xml");
 var q = from c in loaded.Descendants("module")
 where (int)c.Attribute("ModuleID") < 0
 select (string)c.Attribute("Text");
```

From the above xml file i want to get  tag attributes values.

```
Text="Basic Settings" ModID="Mod1" ModuleID="1" MenuType="0" Perm="False"
```

From the above xml i want to get all  tag attributes values .

**How to get value from an *xml*  file?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or you can in the last step cast to XElement and use whatever XElement has to offer:

instead of var q:

```
IEnumerable<XElement> q =from c in loaded.Descendants("module") 
                    where (int)c.Attribute("ModuleID").Value < 0 
                    select c;

foreach(XElement e in q){
   string t = e.Attribute("Text").Value;
   // etc...
}
```

if you know one record is going to be return

```
XElement q = (from c in loaded.Descendants("module") 
                    where (int)c.Attribute("ModuleID").Value < 0 
                    select c).First(); // one of many options to return a single record

sring t = q.Attribute("Text").Value;
// etc...
```

**UPDATE**

to make further queries to your result:

```
IEnumarble<XElement> menus = q.Elements("menu");
```

then loop foreach, you can use `menuselement.Element("tag_name").Value` to get string values of the nodes, or `menuselement.Attribute("attr_name").Value` to get attribute values, and you can further query with menuslement.Find or `menuselement.Where` or `menuselement.Select` and the options are really limitless... here is where you can learn more:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387065.aspx

And here is MSDN's how to query xml using linq:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb943906.aspx

Comment: im not 100% sure of (int) to cast, if it works for you great, but it never works for me, i usually have to go with Convert.toInt16(val)

Comment: How to select all menu tag values.Menu tag contain leaf,submenu tag's.want to select all values of the menu tag and fill AspxMenu by this value.

Answer (score 2):

Well it looks like you're nearly there:

```
XDocument loaded = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Menu_Settings.xml");

var q = from c in loaded.Descendants("module")
        where (int)c.Attribute("ModuleID") < 0
        select new
        {
             Text = (string) c.Attribute("Text"),
             ModID = (string) c.Attribute("ModID"),
             ModuleID = (int) c.Attribute("ModuleID"),
             MenuType = (int) c.Attribute("MenuType"),
             Perm = (bool) c.Attribute("Perm")
        };
```

If that doesn't help you, please give more details.

Comment: Hi Jon, you're missing commas at the end of some lines here I think?

Comment: want to select all menu tag and  AspxMenu fill by this value.menu tag contain leaf and submenu tag.How to select all value.

Comment: plz follow this url.There i describe my problme.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3458700/how-to-aspxmenu-fill-from-xml-file

Comment: @shamim: It doesn't really - it just repeats the same phrase, which doesn't make sense. I realise English probably isn't our first language, but please make another attempt to describe what you're trying to do.